# Facebook pixel dashboard apis

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook pixel apis to track visitors on my website.

I found several apis for creating Facebook pixel, ads using various sdks and using curl.

**What I am looking for is** :

Does facebook provide api's for reports (**matrix**) it generate on its ads(pixel dashboard) manager dashboard.

**as an example** [image: facebook pixel dashboard]

**I am looking for apis using which I can**

- know how many pixel are fired
- **target audience or group of audience who have done, visited certain  pages**

One way of doing this is using dashboard, but **can we do this using apis**?.

I tried to find but dint get apis for this, If I missed something Please do let me know.

Thanks..!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? There does not seem to be anything in the docs...

Comment: no, did'nt find

Comment: Any update about this topic?